# Web Services and Proxy Servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web application that I distribute to clients that is installed on a Web server. Currently, once a quarter user will download an XML file from an external URL on one of our Web servers. The application then takes that XML data and updates the application's database. Every so often a client will come to me and say, "I can't download the XML file" so then I have to get in contact with the client's IT department to let the application request from external data sources. My assumption is that they set up a rule in their proxy server.

My question is, if I set up my application to use a web service hosted on my Web server will I still have the same problem?

Thank you in advance,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

This really has to do with the client's network setup. A lot of companies install proxies that only allow requests from a whitelist. If you used your own server, it would not be any different, because your server may not be in that whitelist either.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was afraid of